# What is a Mashape Key?

Tags: python, request, unirest

I am doing some tests and I would like to make a successful request using [these](https://market.mashape.com/omgvamp/hearthstone) API.
I tried to make a request as follows:

```
response = unirest.get("https://omgvamp-hearthstone- 
v1.p.mashape.com/cards/Ysera",
  headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "<required>",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
)
```

but I get the following:

```
>>> response.code
403
```

How can I fulfill my request? What is the X-Mashape-Key field? Why do I need it?

Comment: I have no experience with mashape.com, but from a quick look it looks like you need to sign up in order to obtain the key: https://imgur.com/C3RayAK

Comment: `X-...` are for **private** use. Ask mashape.com for what it is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the "X-Mashape-Key" seems to be some sort of authorization. The 403 error means that the server is denying the request even with authorization. It seems that the request isn't possible to the given url. Are you sure you are able to make requests to that URL. Try doing it manually using a GET requests using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library and sending the headers with the request.
Here is some more information on the [403](https://httpstatuses.com/403) error.

Answer (score 2):

Mashape API Marketplace merged with RapidAPI

https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2017/10/16/1230930/0/en/Mashape-Rebrands-as-Kong-Inc-Declares-Monolithic-Application-Dead.html
https://rapidapi.com/blog/rapidapi-and-mashape-api-marketplace-join-forces/

> Creating an app within RapidAPI generates an API key (`X-RapidAPI-Key`) specific to that application.

source: https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys